# remove string dynamically before insert in mysql

Tags: php

I have tried a new thing . I am not sure if its correct or not but unfortunately its not working but also not giving any problem. :( :)

I am trying to remove some specific text from the title before it get insert into DB. So here is my code

```
$rows = array();
$hdate=date("l, Fj, Y");
foreach($obj->rss->channel->item as $item) 
{
    $rows[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("Horoscope for $hdate ", '', "$item->title"))."','".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description)."')";
}
```

I am trying to remove String "Horoscope for Friday, April 26, 2013" from each row. The title looks like  "Aries Horoscope for Friday, April 26, 2013" . Since the day also updates everyday so I have declared the hDate format . Here is my DB inserted looks like 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzChX.png

The above works perfectly but still after running the code it dont delete the string form the title.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to remove "Horoscope for Friday, April 26, 2013" means you only want "Aries" instead of "Aries Horoscope for Friday, April 26, 2013"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Aries Horoscope for Friday, April 26, 2013

echo $hdate=date("l, Fj, Y");

//Thursday, April25, 2013

echo $hdate=date("l, F j, Y"); //use this

//Thursday, April 25, 2013
```

may be this help

```
preg_replace('{Horoscope for.*}','',$title);
```